# How do I add product thumbnails in Magento?

Tags: magento, thumbnails

I am trying to show five product-related thumbnails just below the product image (to let the customers see the product from different angles). But I can't figure it out how to add these thumbnails in the backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the admin dashboard, navigate to Catalog > Manage Products.

Within the manage products view select the left navigation item "Images".

When you upload images, to have them show in the "media gallery" below the main product **do not** select any of the radio options (Base Image, Small Image, Thumbnail).  These remaining images that do not have an image type will show below the main product.

The thumbnail image selection in this Images panel is used to provided images for related, upsell, cross-sell blocks and cart images.

If your product is a configurable product, follow the steps above for the configurable item.

Comment: Thanks Anthony for such detailed explanation... it was very easy I got it working...cheers